$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{3}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2+k}\right)$

Calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{3}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2+k}\right).$$

I used the Squeeze Theorem and got an answer $-1/4$, but that's too complex. So can anybody use calculus to do that?

Squeeze theorem should be calculus too.

Use
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},\quad \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},$$
we get that
$$\frac{n}{3}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2+k}
=n\left(\frac{1}{3}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n(n^2+k)}\right)\\
=n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k^2}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n(n^2+k)}\right)\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-(3n+1)}{(n+1)(2n+1)(n^2+k)}\cdot k^2
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k^3-(3n+1)k^2}{(n+1)(2n+1)(n^2+k)}.$$
So
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k^3-(3n+1)k^2}{(n+1)(2n+1)n^2}
<\frac{n}{3}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2+k}
\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k^3-(3n+1)k^2}{(n+1)(2n+1)(n^2+n)},$$
it is easy to see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k^3-(3n+1)k^2}{(n+1)(2n+1)n^2}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k^3-(3n+1)k^2}{(n+1)(2n+1)(n^2+n)}
=\frac14-\frac12=-\frac{1}4.$$
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{3}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2+k}\right)=-\frac{1}4.$$

Using the formula $\frac{1}{1+a} = 1 - a + \frac{a^2}{1+a}$, we can write
$$ \frac{k^2}{n^2+k}
= \frac{k^2}{n^2(1 + \frac{k}{n^2})}
= \frac{k^2}{n^2} - \frac{k^3}{n^4} + \frac{k^4}{n^6(1 + \frac{k}{n^2})}. $$
Then we can decompose the sum as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{3} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^2}{n^2+k}
&= \frac{n}{3} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k^2}{n^2} - \frac{k^3}{n^4} + \frac{k^4}{n^6(1 + \frac{k}{n^2})} \right) \\
&= \frac{n}{3} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^2}{n^2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^3}{n^4} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{n^6(1 + \frac{k}{n^2})} \\
&= \underbrace{ \frac{n}{3} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2} + \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{n^4} }_{ =: A_n} - \underbrace{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{n^6(1 + \frac{k}{n^2})} }_{=:\varepsilon_n}.
\end{align*}
Now, it is easy to check that $A_n \to -\frac{1}{4}$. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
|\varepsilon_n|
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{n^6}
= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{n^4} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \right)
\to 0 \left( \int_{0}^{1} x^4 \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
= 0,
\end{align*}
hence $\varepsilon \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore the limit exists with the value $-\frac{1}{4}$.

The equation 1/1+a=1-a+a^2/1+a looks so amazing!How did you think of it?

@xukuncai, This is in fact the Taylor's approximation for the geometric series in disguise! Specifically, what we really need here is the Taylor's approximation $\frac{1}{1+a}=1-a+\mathcal{O}(a^2)$, and in this case the implicit error term $\mathcal{O}(a^2)$ turns out to take a simple form, namely $\frac{a^2}{1+a}$, via the well-known identity: $$\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$$

Start writing
$$A_k=\frac{k^2}{k+n^2}=\frac{(k+n^2)^2-2(k+n^2)n^2+n^4}{k+n^2}$$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+n^2)-2n^2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1 + n^4\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k+n^2}$$
$$S_n=\Big(\frac{1}{2} \left(2 n^3+n^2+n\right)  \Big)-2n^2\Big(n \Big)+ n^4\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k+n^2}$$
For the last summation, using harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k+n^2}=H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}$$ Combining all the above
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 n^3+n^2+n\right)+n^4\big( H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}\big)$$
Now, using the asymptotic
$$H_p=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12 p^2}+\frac{1}{120 p^4}
+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right)$$
$$S_n=\frac{n}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{15n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Then, the result
